# How to dynamically assign border color using geom_node_circle?

Tags: r, border, ggraph, geom

I'm trying to change the borders of nodes in `ggraph` using `geom_node_circle`. I want to set the border colors based on a mapping between the names of the nodes and the colors that I supply for the names. I know that the parameter to change the border is `colour`.

Make graph for example:

```
df <- data_frame(group = c("animals","animals","pets","pets","pets","wild animals","wild animals"),
                 subgroup = c("pets","wild animals","rabbit","dog","cat","polar bear","panda bear"))

df <- as.data.frame(table(df))
df <- filter(df, Freq > 0)

vertices <- df %>%
  dplyr::distinct(subgroup, Freq) %>%
  dplyr::add_row(subgroup = "animals", Freq = 0)

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = vertices)
```

I know how to change all of the borders to a single new color (red):

```
ggraph(graph, layout = "circlepack", weight = Freq) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill =depth),colour = "red") +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, size = 5)
```

But, I don't know how to assign the border based on the mapping between `name` in `graph` and my colors.

**Attempt A**

Make map and apply to `ggraph`:

```
my_colors <- c("black","black","red","black","black","black","black","black")
names(my_colors) <- c("animals","pets","wild animals","rabbit","dog","cat","polar bear","panda bear")

ggraph(graph, layout = "circlepack", weight = Freq) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill =depth),colour = my_colors) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, size = 5)
```

Returns

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2888): colour
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**Attempt B**

Add color column to original `df` and apply to `ggraph`:

```
df$my_colors <- cbind(df, ifelse(df$subgroup=="wild animals", "red", "black")

ggraph(graph, layout = "circlepack", weight = Freq) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill =depth),colour = df$my_colors) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, size = 5)
```

Returns the same error as before.

When I look at the graph, I can see that `my_colors` isn't there:

```
create_layout(graph, 'circlepack', weight = Freq)
```

```
Non-leaf weights ignored
           x          y         r circular  leaf depth         name Freq .ggraph.orig_index .ggraph.index
1  0.0000000  0.0000000 2.3440385    FALSE FALSE     0      animals    0                  8             1
2  0.7244867 -0.8650770 1.2156595    FALSE FALSE     1         pets    1                  4             2
3 -0.7805260  0.9319910 1.1283791    FALSE FALSE     1 wild animals    1                  7             3
4  0.2584208 -0.4098895 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2          cat    1                  1             4
5  1.3517237 -0.6890459 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2          dog    1                  2             5
6 -0.5085709  0.4376730 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2   panda bear    1                  3             6
7 -1.0524811  1.4263089 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2   polar bear    1                  5             7
8  0.5633157 -1.4962957 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2       rabbit    1                  6             8
```

**Attempt C**

Try adding `my_color` to `vertices`:

```
vertices$my_color <- ifelse(vertices$subgroup=="wild animals", "red", "black")

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = vertices)

# check if my_color is there
create_layout(graph, 'circlepack', weight = Freq)
```

I can see `my_color` is now in `graph`:

```
Non-leaf weights ignored
            x          y         r circular  leaf depth         name Freq my_color .ggraph.orig_index .ggraph.index
1  0.00000000  0.0000000 2.3440387    FALSE FALSE     0      animals    0    black                  8             1
2  0.42321874  1.0460045 1.2156596    FALSE FALSE     1         pets    1    black                  4             2
3 -0.45595483 -1.1269132 1.1283791    FALSE FALSE     1 wild animals    1      red                  7             3
4  1.05259805  1.2142151 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2          cat    1    black                  1             4
5  0.25420381  0.4168406 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2          dog    1    black                  2             5
6 -0.05740794 -0.7275760 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2   panda bear    1    black                  3             6
7 -0.85450171 -1.5262505 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2   polar bear    1    black                  5             7
8 -0.03714565  1.5069576 0.5641896    FALSE  TRUE     2       rabbit    1    black                  6             8
```

But if I run

```
ggraph(graph, layout = "circlepack", weight = Freq) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill =depth),colour = my_color) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, size = 5)
```

I get

```
Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = StatNodeCircle,  : 
  object 'my_color' not found
```

So, then I figured that I just don't know how to access attributes from `graph` but I figured that out and assigned it to the border color using `colour = V(graph)$my_color`. That still results in the same error indicating that the length of data is 2888. I assume that this error is being thrown because my list of colors is less than that.

**Thoughts**

I'm new to using `ggraph`, and I think that I'm lacking some fundamental knowledge to figure this out....

**Solution**

Modified from @DanAdams original answer:

```
df <- data_frame(group = c("animals","animals","pets","pets","pets","wild animals","wild animals"),
                 subgroup = c("pets","wild animals","rabbit","dog","cat","polar bear","panda bear"))

df <- as.data.frame(table(df))
df <- filter(df, Freq > 0)

vertices <- df %>%
  dplyr::distinct(subgroup, Freq) %>%
  dplyr::add_row(subgroup = "animals", Freq = 0)

vertices$my_color <- ifelse(vertices$subgroup=="wild animals", "red", "black")

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = vertices)

ggraph(graph, layout = "circlepack", weight = Freq) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill =depth,colour = my_color)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, size = 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need to add `color = name` inside of the `aes()`.

I also colored the labels to match to make it easier to follow.

As @user8121557 points out in the comments, if left unspecified in `geom_node_circle()`, the `group` aesthetic will be governed by `fill` when a discrete scale is provided. This causes some of the circles to get plotted *below* the `fill` and be invisible if the `alpha` is `1` (default behavior). Therefore it's necessary to explicitly include a `group` aesthetic too to ensure the circles are all in the same layer on top.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

df <- data_frame(group = c("animals","animals","pets","pets","pets","wild animals","wild animals"),
                 subgroup = c("pets","wild animals","rabbit","dog","cat","polar bear","panda bear"))

my_colors <- c("black","black","red","black","black","black","black","black")
names(my_colors) <- c("animals","pets","wild animals","rabbit","dog","cat","polar bear","panda bear")

df <- as.data.frame(table(df))
df <- filter(df, Freq > 0)

vertices <- df %>%
  dplyr::distinct(subgroup, Freq) %>%
  dplyr::add_row(subgroup = "animals", Freq = 0)

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = vertices)

ggraph(graph, layout = "circlepack", weight = Freq) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill = depth, colour = name, group = depth), size = 1) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name, color = name), repel = TRUE, size = 5, show.legend = F) +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_colors)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had to be missing something simple. The only thing missing from your answer is that the colors are auto-assigned from a palette, not specified by the user. I'll edit my post to show how I modified your answer to more completely achieve what I want.

Comment: The nesting for the bubbles seems to get thrown off by this. You can see in your plot that there's a bubble for rabbit but not dog or cat. My real data has a deeper hierarchy, and the bubbles only nest two deep. I've fiddled with the code a bit to try to fix this but haven't found a solution nor do I understand why the border argument affects this.

Comment: weird... they are still there but they seem to be under the `fill`. If you adjust `alpha = 0.5` in the circle, you'll see them. Not sure how to bring the circle above the `fill` though or why only some of the circles are on top.

Comment: I found the fix for the fill/nesting issue. Change `geom_node_circle(aes(fill = depth, color = name)` to `geom_node_circle(aes(fill = depth, colour = name, group = depth))`. "The issue is that setting fill to a discrete variable will set the grouping aesthetic...."--https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/230

Comment: Nice find. I'll update my answer accordingly.